# How do I return a model from a view's form with AJAX jQuery

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

On a view I have a form:

```
<div>
     @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { id = "TCPForm" }))
     {
        <h4>Request</h4>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HttpRequest, new {name="HttpRequest"})
        <h4>Port Nunber</h4>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HttpPortNumber, new { name ="HttpPortNumber"})
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HttpRequestType, HttpRequestType.Get, new {@Id = "get"})
         <label for="get">Get</label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HttpRequestType, HttpRequestType.Post, new {@Id = "post"})
         <label for="post">Post</label>
      }
      <p></p>
      <input type="submit" id="TCPSubmit" value="Send Request" />
</div>
```

The Submit button is outside of the form as I intercept it with jQuery.

Then I have this Jquery to intercept the button press, show a spinner and get the results via Ajax:

```
        $('#TCPSubmit').click(function () {
        $('#resultPaneTCP').html("<div class='spinner'><div class='dot1'></div><div class='dot2'></div></div>");
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SendTcpMessage", "TestandDevelopment")",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#TCPForm').serialize(),
            datatype: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#resultPaneTCP').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This is the Action signature:

```
    public ActionResult SendTcpMessage(HttpViewModel httpViewModel)
    {
```

This the Model I send to the view and which gets edited in the form:

```
    public class HttpViewModel 
    {
       public string HttpRequest { get; set; }
       public string HttpResponse { get; set; }
       public string HttpRequestType { get; set; }
       public string HttpPortNumber { get; set; }

       public HttpViewModel()
       {
       }

       public HttpViewModel(string httpRequest, string httpResponse)
       {
           this.HttpRequest = httpRequest;
           this.HttpResponse = httpResponse;
       }
}
```

When I run the above and press the button in the View, the Spinner gets shown, the Action fires but the Model in the Action signature is empty.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewmodel and action signature are okay, but you need to reconfigure your view a bit, particularly with how you have declared `@Html.BeginForm()` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor()`. In my example below, I am using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `@Html.BeginForm()` and [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830410%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `@Html.RadioButtonFor()`.

Also, I use `"Controller"` for the controller name (once in the HTML and once in the jQuery snippet) — make sure to replace that with your actual controller.

```
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SendTcpMessage", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "TCPForm" }))
        {
            <h4>Request</h4>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HttpRequest, new { name = "HttpRequest" })
            <h4>Port Nunber</h4>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HttpPortNumber, new { name = "HttpPortNumber" })
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HttpRequestType, "Get" )
            <label for="get">Get</label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HttpRequestType, "Post" )
            <label for="post">Post</label>
            <input type="submit" id="TCPSubmit" value="Send Request" />
        }                      
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#TCPSubmit').click(function (e) {
            //no need to place the submit button outside of the form
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SendTcpMessage", "Controller")",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#TCPForm').serialize(),
                datatype: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Adding a breakpoint to the `SendTcpMessage` action shows that `httpViewModel` is now populated with the values passed by the form:

[image: httpViewModel is now populated]

Comment: It's not clear to me what the actual problem was; can either of you shed any light on this?